# Ubuntu conda Python3.9 can not find numpy

Tags: python, numpy, conda

I can not use Mumpy with Ubuntu, Python 3.9 in Anaconda. But I have installed it. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: When you use `sudo` your environment, like your virtualenv settings, is not preserved. You probably don't need `sudo`, but you can also try `sudo -E` to see if that helps any.

Comment: @sytech sorry sir, it is still not work

Comment: Please don't share screen output as a screenshot. Always copy-paste text into your question. Can you check what `type python` gives you?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the point of virtual environments, like those created by conda, are that you *don't* need root ("administrator") privileges to build and install software, so you shouldn't need `sudo`; just run `python setup.py develop`.  You may need other things installed (compilers and development libraries) for that to work.

You've already confirmed `numpy` is installed via your `conda install` and `pip install` commands, but you could also run `python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"` as further confirmation that it's working.

Pytorch [is already packaged for conda](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch) - have you tried the command listed at that link?